# Evaluate the following Determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Find $$ \Delta=\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{1}{a+x} &\frac{1}{b+x}  &\frac{1}{c+x} \\ 
 \frac{1}{a+y} &\frac{1}{b+y}  &\frac{1}{c+y} \\ 
\frac{1}{a+z} &\frac{1}{b+z}  &\frac{1}{c+z}
\end{vmatrix}$$

I applied $C_1 \to C_1-C_2$ and $C_2 \to C_2-C_3$ we get

$$ \Delta=\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{b-a}{(a+x)(b+x)} &\frac{c-b}{(b+x)(c+x)}  &\frac{1}{c+x} \\ 
 \frac{b-a}{(a+y)(b+y)} &\frac{c-b}{(b+y)(c+y)}&\frac{1}{c+y} \\ 
\frac{b-a}{(a+z)(b+z)} &\frac{c-b}{(b+z)(c+z)}  &\frac{1}{c+z}
\end{vmatrix}$$

Now taking $b-a$,$\:$$c-b$ common and taking $$\frac{1}{(a+x)(b+x)(c+x)(a+y)(b+y)(c+y)(a+z)(b+z)(c+z)}$$ outside Determinant we get

$$\Delta=\frac{(b-a)(c-b)}{(a+x)(b+x)(c+x)(a+y)(b+y)(c+y)(a+z)(b+z)(c+z)} \times \begin{vmatrix}
c+x &a+x &(a+x)(b+x) \\ 
c+y &a+y &(a+y)(b+y)\\ 
c+z &a+z &(a+z)(b+z)
\end{vmatrix}$$

Now apply $C_1 \to C_1-C_2$ we get

$$\Delta=\frac{(b-a)(c-b)(c-a)}{(a+x)(b+x)(c+x)(a+y)(b+y)(c+y)(a+z)(b+z)(c+z)} \times \begin{vmatrix}
1 &a+x &(a+x)(b+x) \\ 
1 &a+y &(a+y)(b+y)\\ 
1 &a+z &(a+z)(b+z)
\end{vmatrix}$$

any clue  here?

Comment: There's a [formula for 3x3 determinants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#3_.C3.97_3_matrices), so why not simply use that ?

Comment: Also, google for Cauchy determinant.

Comment: I am not sure but this matrix looks like a Cauchy-Matrix where we have an explicit formula for the determinant. Maybe this may help. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_matrix. Edit: Seems like I was too slow.

Comment: You could add to your post that you are trying to evaluate it using property of determinants, lest anyone mentions that there is the Sarrus's rule or any other method to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\Delta&=\begin{vmatrix} \frac{1}{a+x} & \frac{1}{b+x} & \frac{1}{c+x} \\  \frac{1}{a+y} & \frac{1}{b+y} & \frac{1}{c+y} \\ \frac{1}{a+z} & \frac{1}{b+z} & \frac{1}{c+z}\end{vmatrix}\\
\left[\prod_{q\in\{x,y,z\}}(a+q)\right]\Delta&=\begin{vmatrix} 1 & \frac{a+x}{b+x} & \frac{a+x}{c+x} \\  1 & \frac{a+y}{b+y} & \frac{a+y}{c+y} \\ 1 & \frac{a+z}{b+z} & \frac{a+z}{c+z}\end{vmatrix}\\
\left[\prod_{p\in\{a,b\}}\prod_{q\in\{x,y,z\}}(p+q)\right]\Delta&=\begin{vmatrix} b+x & a+x & \frac{(a+x)(b+x)}{c+x} \\  b+y & a+y & \frac{(a+y)(b+y)}{c+y} \\ b+z & a+z & \frac{(a+z)(b+z)}{c+z}\end{vmatrix}\\
\left[\prod_{p\in\{a,b,c\}}\prod_{q\in\{x,y,z\}}(p+q)\right]\Delta&=\begin{vmatrix} (b+x)(c+x) & (c+x)(a+x) & (a+x)(b+x) \\  (b+y)(c+y) & (c+y)(a+y) & (a+y)(b+y) \\ (b+z)(c+z) & (c+z)(a+z) & (a+z)(b+z)\end{vmatrix}
\end{align}

Let $\displaystyle \Delta_0=\begin{vmatrix} (b+x)(c+x) & (c+x)(a+x) & (a+x)(b+x) \\  (b+y)(c+y) & (c+y)(a+y) & (a+y)(b+y) \\ (b+z)(c+z) & (c+z)(a+z) & (a+z)(b+z)\end{vmatrix}$.

Note that $\Delta_0=0$ when $a=b$, $b=c$, $c=a$, $x=y$, $y=z$ and $z=x$.

Since $\Delta_0$ is a polynomial of degree $6$ in $a,b,c,x,y,z$,

$$\Delta_0=k(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)$$

for some constant $k$.

Put $a=x=1$, $b=y=0$ and $c=z=-1$.

\begin{align}
\begin{vmatrix} 0 & 0 & 2 \\  0 & -1 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 & 0\end{vmatrix}&=k(1)(1)(-2)(1)(1)(-2)\\
k&=1
\end{align}

Therefore,

$$\Delta=\frac{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)}{(a+x)(a+y)(a+z)(b+x)(b+y)(b+z)(c+x)(c+y)(c+z)}$$